# Login button in top menu

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, mobile-web, top-bar

I frequently visit Stackexchange sites on my iPhone. Mostly I am already logged-in, but sometimes I get auto-logged out. I want to re-login as fast as possible.

Currently I have to click on the site logo to open a sub menu and under `Your communities` I am able to login or signup. This annoys me.

I am also sure that new users who want to signup using their smartphone should know exactly where to signup. I don't think the sub-menu is right place for that.

Could we get that button in the top (right) menu?

[image: example 1][image: example 2]

Answer (score 3):

This has been released in [Mobile web refresher, part 2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237518/mobile-web-refresher-part-2)