# Login text appears misaligned on windows phone 8

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, mobile-web, windows-phone

I have few issues after [recent update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237518/168386) to mobile web of www.StackOverflow.com

1. Login text appears misaligned on windows phone 8
2. I am not able to login from my windows phone 8 (Lumia 525)
3. Notice two links showing up for "forgot password" (other one is slit snipped in screenshot)
4. Notice the login button going out of box in "Log in using Stack Exchange".

For issue #1: Check the image below.
For issue #2: when I click on google or facebook or any other openid links nothing happens.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This should be fixed in build <del>2447</del> 2448 -- however please double check on your phone because I can't test it.

Comment: Some points are done but issue #3 and #4 are still there.

Comment: One more thing, you can test these changes in IE 11 in emulation mode so kindly test yourself once before marking this as complete. This is my kind to update question so as to remove 'status-completed' tag until anyone actually have proof of it being [done](http://www.scrumalliance.org/community/articles/2008/september/what-is-definition-of-done-(dod)).

Comment: i simply put in the wrong rev number... but no, I can't "simply test on ie 11" and guarantee it won't break on winphone.

Comment: Agree but you will have at least some approx idea at hand. I checked in IE 11 and windows phone and UX/UI was same in both. I would say try solving these issues in IE 11; later I or someone else can confirm in actual device. :)

Comment: That's what I meant