# I don't how but now I am facing auto login issue on windows phone

Tags: bug, mobile-web, logout, windows-phone

I have been facing [Not able to login](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237556/168386) issue on random days until now. Just now I have other kind of issue.

Steps I tried:

1. Clear all the browser history which also cleans cookies (it says).
2. Open www.StackOverflow.com and it shows login link on home page.
3. Go to login page, do nothing.
4. I am again on home page with myself logged without clicking

Note: In step #3 Quickly navigate to bottom of login page and observe it says "Blah Blah you have been auto logged.. redirecting something.."

I am using Windows Phone 8, Lumia 525 model.

Please help.

### Update

Check the screen shots below:

### 1. Open side menu

[image]

### 2. Logout page says it will clear all local credentials, ok please logout.. Click!

[image]

### 3. Visit Login page and at the bottom of page it says welcome back to me but in logout page it said we will clear whole thing locally about your login. :(

[image]

Comment: Sorry, how is this a bug? What's the problem exactly? You go to the login page and get logged in.

Comment: I have logged out from www.StackOverflow.com then how I am logged in again? What if I am using someone else's phone and now I am permanent in his phone. :(

Comment: You went to the login page - not that surprising that you get logged back in. When it comes to logins, you need to log out of your openId provider as well in order to be properly logged out.

Comment: @Oded Logout page says OpenId is `facebook`. So I checked fb in same tab and fb shows me logged out then how I am logged in again?

Comment: Logout page doesn't tell you which of the (possibly several different OpenId providers) is being used. From the gmail.com part, it could be that you are logged in to your google account (which also serves as an OpenId provider).

Comment: Check the screenshot in question. It actually says which OpenId I am logged with. Also I am not even logged with gmail :P

Comment: Sure, but if you are logged in with **any** OpenId provider linked to your account, you will get logged in automatically.

Comment: I have checked again, I'm NOT logged in any of these - Facebook, Google, Wordpress, Yahoo or Outlook which are linked with my account.

Comment: Then logging out should log you out, and you shouldn't be able to automatically log back in.