# .answered-accepted style isn't defined in StackOverflow mobile site

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, accepted-answer, mobile-web

In my opinion, mobile site has updated in the last days. And I have noticed one issue, in user profile page we can't know if our answer is accepted or not. But, in full version and the previous mobile version it was working. Here is the snapshots:

**In full site**:

[image]

---

**In mobile site:**

[image]

If you can see four answers are accepted by the answerers in full site. I have inspected these elements and the class name is `answered-accepted`. It is also added to the elements in mobile site. But, isn't defined there.

It is not very big thing, but I hope so it will be fixed. ;)

Comment: I already [noticed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237599/259214) ;-)

Comment: @nicael Thanks for the link. I have searched, but didn't find this. And I was thinking it is only me in the world, who has noticed that. ))

Comment: @nicael true, but guess it's time to post those bugs and/or requests as new questions as the team no longer pays attention to that "thread". (guess they were just looking for urgent/horrible bugs in there)